# How to pull all the nested child nodes from an XML?

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

I have a simple XML with nested grandChild nodes like this

```
<parent>
    <child type="reference">
        <grandChild name="aaa" action="None">
            <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            <grandChild name="bbb" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            </grandChild>
            <grandChild name="ccc" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
            </grandChild>
        </grandChild>
        <grandChild name="ddd" action="None">
                <Attribute name="xxx">1</Attribute>
        </grandChild>
    </child>
</parent>
```

And I want to pull list of all the grandChild nodes only. I'm able to achieve while iterating each node, and that gives me list of one level but not for whole XML. Is it possible to achieve it with single dataweave?

My simple dataweave looks like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.parent.child.*grandChild.*grandChild map {
    "@name": $.@name,
    "Attribute" : $.*Attribute map {
        "@name" : $.@name,
        "#text" : trim($)
    }
}
```

Desired output

```
[
  {
    "@name": "bbb",
    "Attribute": [
      {
        "@name": "xxx",
        "#text": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@name": "ccc",
    "Attribute": [
      {
        "@name": "xxx",
        "#text": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@name": "aaa",
    "Attribute": [
      {
        "@name": "xxx",
        "#text": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@name": "ddd",
    "Attribute": [
      {
        "@name": "xxx",
        "#text": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
payload..*grandChild map ( ( elt, index) ->
    {
        "@name": elt.@name,
        "Attribute": elt.*Attribute map ( (attrElt, attrIndex) ->
        {  "@name": attrElt.@name,
            "#text": trim(attrElt)
        }
        )
    }
)
```